# How to resolve this warning " W/Atlas﹕Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables? "

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

**Every time when I run my app, I'm getting this weird warning!**

*I don't have any idea about resolving it. Can some one please explain me this!*

`*Here is the logcat.*`

```
06-25 09:34:24.997    1721-1721/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-25 09:34:25.957    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
06-25 09:34:25.970    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa4942590, tid 1721
06-25 09:34:25.975    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:25.979    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
```

and it goes.. up to this. so I skipped some lines.

```
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.019    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.025    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.025    1721-1721/com.aitrg.aitqc W/Atlas﹕ Pointer 0x0, not in getPreloadedDrawables?
06-25 09:34:26.087    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-25 09:34:26.088    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-25 09:34:26.100    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-25 09:34:26.115    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa4942b30, tid 1748
06-25 09:34:26.125    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-25 09:34:26.160    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-25 09:34:26.183    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-25 09:34:26.183    1721-1748/com.aitrg.aitqc W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4938f80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Are you getting above warning for specific device only or on all? As per source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5795d64/core/java/android/view/ThreadedRenderer.java#395) , it may happen if all drawable resources are not loaded properly IMO.

Comment: @iAnum for specif application! I don't think it came for specific device! coz I got the same error on emulator and my lenovo device.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error, and I'm running Hello World!

Comment: @ScottBiggs I'm getting this error while using emulator, try to use any device and check whether it is still throwing this warning!

Comment: @praneethkumar Good suggestion: my phone does not have those errors when running Hello World.  But the Genymotion emulator does.  So it may be a problem with the emulator (running on a Mac).  And I'm also using Android Studio 2.0, the latest stable build.

Answer (score -1):

Try set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

I got same problem when using gif movie icons.

It works for me.